# kibana not showing data or any visualize graph

Tags: elasticsearch, settings, kibana, kibana-4

I'm trying to setup Kibana, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have manage to setup index properly and it recognized all 36 fields.

I have 100 rows in the elastic search, but it seems to be  not working.

Can someone guide me of what I'm doing wrong?

Basically I have geo_point on two fields and I want to show data on the map.

https://search-searchd-6s3ydjr63b2djl6gj6227wqwea.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/#/dashboard?_g=()&_a=(filters:!(),panels:!(),query:(query_string:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top right, you can see that the time interval is "Last 15 minutes". The reason might simply be that you might not have data in the last 15 minutes.

If you click on that button you can change the considered time interval, maybe pick "Last 7 days" or another time frame that you know will contain data, and you will start to see data.

Then you can create a Tile Map visualization on either/both your pickup or dropoff geo point field and you'll be able to see some data on the map.

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot.

Comment: Also don't forget to secure your Kibana, it's not a good idea to leave open to the world like that. At least I would obfuscate the link in your question.

Comment: Defo.  now I know what is the purpose of precision and how it works lol.. Thank you, I'm still newbie for kibana, but defo will secure once everything is going well.